# Popularity trend report always 0

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, statistics

DETAILS BELOW
[image]

Ok, so ive now been troubleshooting why our Popularity reports are always getting a zero and i feel i am very close.

Log files are being populated
databases are being populated
usage files are being created

Event Store folder is empty! ( Yes i have checked the sharepoint job Data import and it is enabled )

However i then checked the job which is suppose to run overnight

$job = Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalyticsJobDefinition
$job.GetAnalysisInfo()

and Wallah! it hasnt been ran but i cant seem to find that job in CA to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

This was because there was receiver for the usage services. The below code to be able to query the Service with the below code.

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
$aud | fl
```

Then

```
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud | fl
```

Check for result and find the below parameter.

> Enable receivers="false"
>   Receiver= {}

Notice there is no receiver attached.

The below code will apply the Microsoft extensions.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell 
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"}
```

if analytics usage definition receivers is empty then manually add back receiver

```
if($aud.Receivers.Count -eq 0) 
{ 
    $aud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.AnalyticsCustomRequestUsageReceiver") 
}
```

if analytics usage definition receiver is not enabled then enable it

```
if($aud.EnableReceivers -eq $false) 
{ 
    $aud.EnableReceivers = $true 
    $aud.Update() 
} 
$aud | fl 
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
```

if page requests usage definition receivers is empty then manually add back receiver

```
if($prud.Receivers.Count -eq 0) 
{ 
    $prud.Receivers.Add("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Applications, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c", "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.Internal.ViewRequestUsageReceiver")  
}
```

if page requests usage definition receiver is not enabled then enable it

```
if($prud.EnableReceivers -eq $false) 
{ 
    $prud.EnableReceivers = $true 
    $prud.Update() 
} 
$prud | fl
```

This will apply the receivers. Running the below code we can check the outcome.

```
$aud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Analytics*"} 
$aud | fl
```

Then

```
$prud = Get-SPUsageDefinition | where {$_.Name -like "Page Requests"}
$prud | fl
```

You will find Enable receiver is true and Receiver with path

After 24 hours the reports will start to populate information. This is pending on the timer jobs running which out of the box are set to run daily

Comment: Hi Das, I have already done the above but it didnt work. Just so that you are aware we have Sharepoint 2016.

Comment: I ran the above code two days ago. One thing i have noted is that the folder EventStore is not stored on the C drive?

Comment: It is stored on D:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\16.0\Data\Office Server\Analytics_35d10617-e4a5-46e9-8c54-9b4c85506df4\EventStore

Comment: will update you for 2016 soon